# Implement a division function in Java without the "/" operator

Tags: java

Can somebody suggest ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Have you considered bit shifts?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division

Comment: Is multiplication by a number between 0 and 1 allowed?

Comment: Though it is closed: `BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal( "6" ); BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal( "3" ); BigDecimal c = a.divide(b);`

Comment: Daniel - hahahahaha, nice work around :) Even though that is not what I meant

Comment: Thomas - No, it is not. It is me being curious :) Got done with college long loong time ago

Comment: Simon: That is one possible solution. Multiply by 1/divisor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since division is just a series of repeated substractions, I assume you can do that. (not giving up the full code until you buy me dinner)

Comment: That may take a while :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the substractions or dinner?

Comment: No need for full code :) I will buy you dinner if you pay for your drinks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop, subtracting the amount you're dividing by once per iteration and keeping a count of how many times you've been able to do that. That should be pretty close to an integer division, albeit really inefficient.